# Does the breath literally stop in the fourth Jhāna?

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities, meditation-effects, pali-language, correct-interpretation

I've been trying to understand the descriptions of each of the Jhānas in various Suttas, and I don't get what's meant by an element in some descriptions of the fourth Jhāna. For example:

> When one has attained the fourth jhāna, in-and-out breathing has been totally stilled.

– [SN 36:11](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN36_11.html)

It seems to me that that passage is saying that the breath literally stops, but this seems physiologically impossible. So perhaps the correct interpretation is that *volitional* in-and-out breathing ceases? Or is the passage, perhaps, referring to the *perception* of in-and-out breathing?

I've even gone so far as to look up the words in Pāli, but this has only added to my confusion, since they seem to translate as literally the cessation of breath. Is this, perhaps, a shortcoming of our understanding of Pāli?

If this is to be taken literally, what is the scientific basis for this phenomenon? Is it perhaps a perceptual phenomenon, where the meditator merely perceives the breath as having stopped? Or, if this is indeed an error in interpretation, then how is it to be interpreted?

I should clarify that I'm not seeking to troll, or challenge the tradition. I myself am a lay disciple of the Dhamma. I'm prepared to accept an answer one way or the other, but I really want to have a solid understanding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breathing is imperceptible, that is all, because there must be movement of the breathing for it to be perceived. However, obviously the body continues to have breath flowing through it.

Comment: Hi @Dhammadhatu. Thank you for your answer! What do you mean by "breath flowing through [the body]"?

Comment: The body still breathes but the breathing is not perceptible because the breathing has become so refined.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the explanation that makes the most sense, to be honest. And based on [this forum post](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/mindfulness-of-breathing-an-evolving-approach-to-translation-mn118/4202/68), it seems that a certain translation and interpretation of the same text I linked to supports it.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it,

That which is thought & spoken about as breath is an object of perception and is tied to the body.

In the fourth jhana the object of perception is not thought & spoken about as the breath.

In general the object there is **a kasina**, there are various types of kasina, ie light & colors associated with absorbtion 'visions'.

An interesting circumstance about the passage:

> When one has attained the fourth jhāna, in-and-out breathing has been totally stilled.

Is in the case where the fourth jhana is sustained in dependence on the air element as the air kasina because the in & out breaths are the air element.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem physiologically impossible, and it is so, to the mind, until one experiences it. This is why it is taught that true knowledge comes from direct experiencing (through practice), and not from what one has read, or is told, even by one's teacher/guru (read: guide).

But then consider that deep sea divers, or certain tribes that live by oceans/seas free dive for prolonged periods of time on a single breath. The official Guineas book of record is > 20 minutes... The average swimmer can hold their for 2-3 minutes without breathing.

In my own subjective personal meditations the deeper I go, the shallower I realize I'm breathing. In fact, one of my methods of going in deep, fast, is to still my breath as much as possible, and prolong the holding periods in-between to close to a minute (or more). At a certain point, i consciously let go, and my body subconsciously continues it on its own. Kinda like a subtle hand-over. If I follow my breath, I've gone up to a single breath every 2/3 minutes before I lost sense of my body. And on an occasion or two, I have snapped out of deep meditation to instantaneously realize that I wasn't breathing. And I had no idea how long I was under. It could have been two minutes, it could have been 10.

Thus to me, Science has proof it is possible, but my own personal experiences remove all doubt (for me).

Comment: Hello again @xxandra. I notice you're new. Welcome and thank you for contributing. I'm not sure that the practice of holding your breath in the way you suggest is helpful in the Buddhist domain. This is considered an extreme practice, but in the Buddha's teachings we try to realize a [middle way.](https://encyclopediaofbuddhism.org/wiki/Middle_Way). I think it would be better to edit that part out, otherwise I may flag the answer for moderator inspection.

Comment: True, sounds like yoga - are you sure this answer is not offtopic?

Comment: Yes, @Andrei Volkov. It's off-topic.

Comment: This answer and most of your other answers talk about yoga, siddhi, spirit etc. which are NOT Buddhism. Most of them seem off-topic.

Comment: I am new, and I am not a yogi. When I meditate, I do start with the anchor of breathwork before falling into the middle way. True, it might be extreme, I do not consider myself a lay person. My practices (and life) are more aligned to those of a monk. I follow the teachings of Buddha, but I wasn't born into Bhuddism. In meditating, across the years, all kinds of phenomena arise, and I use modern day terms rather than it would seem, the appropriate terms. But regardless of what words we choose to describe phenomena/practices/states, the phenomena/practices remains the same.

Comment: I find this group refreshing, because I am learning (gradually) all the appropriate lingo (which is new to me). But when I look them up and study them, they are nothing more than different words (in a different language) of my own daily practices / experiences. Flag away if it makes anyone feel better. All it would indicate to me is the display of tunnel vision/narrowmindedness. Bhudda looked down at all men.. I'm afraid as Bhuddism spreads, one will have to accept it spreading across languages as well.But the experience/goal is universal. Please accept my apologies for not conforming a 100%..

Comment: It would be good if you supoorted your answers with textual references because having read the texts, seen your answers and your use of terminology it seems you have little to no familiarity with the early buddhist texts and practices.

Comment: It is probably why your answers come off as those of an outsider. That being said, you should not let anyone here tell you what is and isn't Buddhism because mods should have suspended judgement in regards to these things, that is the official policy (anything is buddhism unless otherwise specified).

Comment: You are also not required to post references or substantiate your claims. So when a mod or anyone tells you it's not Buddhism you can ignore them because it's not up to them to decide. You can also complain to the site admins if the mod is harassing you by playing buddhism police.

Comment: I generally don't like your answers but you should definitely be allowed to post them without mods harassing you. That is simply the current policy here. So mods curb that judgement and keep to moderating spam.

Comment: @8257 You are correct. The texts are in my heart, but not ingrained to the extent that they can roll off my tongue  verbatim or in correct cultural lingo, nor find them easily without looking (read: digging) them up. Born, and with a lifetime of Christianity behind me, I am better versed in that Literature. I guess before (and when, or given the opposition, if) I post again, i shall have to resort to doing some research to substantiate what I say... as well as use the appropriate vernacular, to avoid offending. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I agree with 8527 in principle. It is not our job to police what is and what is not real Buddhism. However when an answer is completely offtopic (for example someone posts a Christian-only answer which by itself may be perfect, just not on topic on this site) then we agreed to try and ask the poster to add some connections to Buddhism or delete the answer. Just a matter of common sense, right? In this case we were on the fence, it may or may not be on topic, which is why I asked it as a question and the other moderator used the word "seems". Other users were less careful with words...

Comment: Let's try and resolve this peacefully by making concessions from both ends. The side that considers these things not Buddhism should try and keep their minds open for other opinions. The side that thinks that posting any answer is okay as long as it's well-intended should try and provide at least *some* connections to a teaching of *any* mainstream school of Buddhism. It will help everyone to avoid these misunderstandings. Thank you all.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov I agree with 8257. And I agree with you about aligning responses to mainstream. I will correct you on two points though. (1) My answer has nothing to do with Christianity. In fact, Christianity considers meditation or any effects of it as demonic... (2) You say the answer is completely off-topic. And yet the question asked is it possible for the breath to stop during meditation? To which my answer said "YES". With two points of proof. 1 of science (i.e. it is possible for the body to live for some time without breathing), and 1 subjective example/instance of my own 4th Jhana.

Comment: You misunderstood :) I used Christianity as an *example* of an offtopic answer because we had several of them in the past. I did not say your answer was completely off-topic or that it was Christian. I was trying to explain why we moderate content at all vs allowing everyone post whatever they want :)

Comment: Noted. But again my answer has/had nothing of Christianity within it. And thus your presumption that my answer is off-topic is wrong, and untrue. But that is of little import.. I am saddened that you closed my question. I was curious to see ensuing opinions, and learn/grow from them. I am also of the opinion that anyone on the path to enlightenment should be able to / or should learn to free the self from emotions in discussion, or not be swayed by the storms of ego. Nor was the question off topic, since it is a very valid concern. But, you are a mod... I'll err to your decision.

Comment: 100% Christianity is just an example of an offtopic answer. I could say 100% Islam, Psychology etc. It was not referring to you, it was an example of an extreme and obvious case requiring/justifying intervention. Yours is much more mild and ambiguous. Again, I did not presume your answer was offtopic, others did but I did not. I asked you to self-check. I'm on your side. Your new question was frozen because it was written in emotional tone and I was worried it would attract more negative comments. I'm trying to help you. Peace.

Comment: In the future you may want to make your answers more obviously connected to Buddhism to avoid situations like this one. I'm locking the comments under this answer. Thank you for your understanding.